# Встроенная покупка работает c Xcode но не работает с Appstore

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchases

Реализовал встроенные покупки, эпл принял версию и залил в стор, щас обнаруживается что в аппстор версии покупки не приходят.

На  appstoreconnect.apple наблюдаю такой статус покупок [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

затем пишут что

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Может кто сталкивался ребята, любая помощь, буду благодарен.

Comment: Так а что в самих покупках, где "необходимо действие разработчика", там все ок? Когда исправите и будет статус "готово к отправке" нужно в разделе, где указываете версию бинарника для выпуска, добавить все покупки с этой версией, для проверки.

Comment: @OlegSoloviev сама версия в сторе которую они приняли, по сути это и есть бинарник правильно? и в нем как раз были реализованы эти покупки. На эпловском форуме наткнулся на такую проблему, у эпл это нормальная практика как оказалось принимать приложение, но оставить на рассмотрение покупки в этом же приложении.

Comment: Нет, нужно исправить на сайте те покупки, где "необходимо действие разработчика", заново сделать бинарник с новой версией и вместе с ней на рассмотрение отправить исправленные покупки.